# Recursive function is not capturing parent DOM node attributes

Tags: javascript, dom

I wrote a recursive function that traverses nested DOM nodes of the following form:

```
<a href="#" title="test">
    <div id="nested-image">
          <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
</a>
```

The recursive function is the following:

```
function getNestedNodes(nodeList) {
var ary = [];
for(var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; ++i) {
    var myJSONChildren = {};
    if(nodeList[i].childElementCount) {
        var htmlCollection = nodeList[i].children;
        for(var j = 0; j < htmlCollection.length; ++j) {
            for(var k =0, attrs = htmlCollection[j].attributes, l = attrs.length; k < l; ++k) {
                myJSONChildren['tag'] = htmlCollection[j].nodeName;
                myJSONChildren[attrs.item(k).nodeName] = attrs.item(k).nodeValue;
            };
        }
        myJSONChildren['children'] = getNestedNodes(htmlCollection);
        ary.push(myJSONChildren);
    };
}
return ary;
}
```

so if I call that function this way:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
console.log(JSON.stringify(getNestedNodes(links)));
```

it should return a JSON array of the following form:

```
[{
  tag:'a',
  href:"#",
  title:"test",
  children:[{
             tag:"div",
             id:"nested-image",
             children:[{
                        tag:"img",
                        src:"image.jpg"
                       }]
             }]
  }]
}]
```

However, it is only returning one of the following form:

```
 [{
   "tag":"DIV",
   "id":"nested-image",
   "children":[{
                "tag":"IMG",
                 "src":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d1a336ae4b6876a4c5c044ec17876ce0",
                "children":[]
              }]
 }]
```

and I haven't been able to get the form that I want in a proper way without getting empty results, or duplicate results.

Also, I'd like to optimize my recursive function, I'm sure that I can be refactored into something more readable.

Here's a fiddle for you to see:

http://jsfiddle.net/DfHqv/

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `function getNestedNodes(node) {` should be `function getNestedNodes(nodeList) {`. `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`. The variable `myNode` is an `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: Indeed, and therefore be passed `node[i].children`.

Comment: Thanks for making my function more readable! @BradChristie so where do I call node[i].children?

Comment: You're already passing `.children`. It's being referenced by your `htmlCollection` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
function getNestedNodes(nodeList) {
    var ary = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i += 1) {
        var attributes = {};
        for (var key in nodeList[i].attributes) {
            attributes[nodeList[i].attributes.item(key).nodeName] = nodeList[i].attributes.item(key).nodeValue;
        }
        ary.push({
            tag: nodeList[i].nodeName,
            attributes: attributes,
            children: getNestedNodes(nodeList[i].children)
        });
    }
    return ary;
}

var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
console.log(JSON.stringify(getNestedNodes(links)));
```

Output:

```
[{"tag":"A","attributes":{"href":"#","title":"test"},"children":[{"tag":"DIV","attributes":{"id":"nested-image"},"children":[{"tag":"IMG","attributes":{"src":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d1a336ae4b6876a4c5c044ec17876ce0?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"},"children":[]}]}]}]
```

Comment: All answers were fantastic, but I think this is the most readable, and I like that you do not only refactored the function but also the JSON Object! Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: @AlanChavez: If you're looking at refactoring, then you may want to check out [JSON ML (JSON markup language)](http://www.jsonml.org/) *(scroll down a bit to see examples)*. It's a very nice and concise way to represent the DOM using valid JSON syntax.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you've made your function to anticipate receiving a collection, yet you're looping two node collections within.

So it seems that you're not pushing in the nodes from the outer loop, but only the children. This would explain why you're not getting the top level.

Just keep it to a single loop of nodes *(and then the one for attributes, of course)*, and then instead of looping the children within a new loop, just pass it in the recursive call.

```
function getNestedNodes(nodeList) {
    var ary = [];

    // Loop the collection of nodes
    for(var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; ++i) {
        var node = nodeList[i];

        // Create the new object with the "tag" populated
        var jsonNode = {"tag":node.nodeName};

        // Add the attributes to the object
        for(var k =0, attrs = node.attributes, l = attrs.length; k < l; ++k) {
            jsonNode[attrs.item(k).nodeName] = attrs.item(k).nodeValue;
        }

        // Make a recursive call if any children are present, and add the result
        if (node.children && node.children.length)
            jsonNode['children'] = getNestedNodes(node.children);

        ary.push(jsonNode);
    }
    return ary;
}
```

---

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/argA3/1/

```
[
    {
        "tag": "A",
        "title": "test",
        "href": "#",
        "children": [
            {
                "tag": "DIV",
                "id": "nested-image",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "tag": "IMG",
                        "src": "image.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we're all prividing various (refactored) bids:

```
// getNestedNodes2(nodeList)
// @nodeList: a collection of nodes to serialize
function getNestedNodes2(nodeList){
    // iterate over the node collection
    for (var i = 0, result = []; i < nodeList.length; i++){
        // begin building a definition of the current node
        var thisNode = {
            tag: nodeList[i].tagName
        };
        // iterate over any attributes on the current node and add them
        // to the current definition.
        for (var j = 0, attributes = nodeList[i].attributes; j < attributes.length; j++){
            thisNode[attributes.item(j).nodeName] = attributes.item(j).nodeValue;
        }
        // check for child elements and, if present, also add them to
        // the definition
        if (nodeList[i].childElementCount > 0){
            thisNode.children = getNestedNodes2(nodeList[i].children);
        }
        // add the definition to the results set
        result.push(thisNode);
    }
    // return the results
    return result;
}
```

and the [end result](http://jsfiddle.net/DfHqv/2/):

```
[
  {
    "tag": "A",
    "title": "test",
    "href": "#",
    "children": [
      {
        "tag": "DIV",
        "id": "nested-image",
        "children": [
          {
            "tag": "IMG",
            "src": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d1a336ae4b6876a4c5c044ec17876ce0?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Keep in mind you're *accepting* a collection in, which means the nodes in that first call are ignored when you go right in to iterating over them and only building a definition of the children. Instead, work on the nodes within the received collection first, then have recursion take care of the children.